# add user certificate to Active Directory - Java

Tags: java, active-directory, x509certificate

I have inherited this code that pulls a userCertificate out of AD:

```
     byte[] userCERT = (byte[])attribs.get("userCertificate").get(); 
     ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( (userCERT)) ;
     CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
     X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);
```

What I need to do now is the exact opposite. A user will submit via the web, their public key. Is it as simple as taking the String and doing a toBytes() on it like this:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(userCertificateString.getBytes()) ;
    Attribute modCert = new BasicAttribute("userCertificate", bais);
    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(context.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, modCert);
    context.modifyAttributes(dn + "," + searchBase, mods);
```

UPDATE:  It is not this simple.  This does not work.
any guidance would be great.

Comment: It does not work.  AD says it wants a DER-encoded X509v3.  SO I figure I have to build one of those from a string somehow and turn that into a byte[]

Answer (score 0):

The final working code is here:

```
   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( (userCertificateString.getBytes())) ;
   CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
   X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);

   System.err.println("<I>" + cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName().toString());
   System.err.println("<S>" + cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName().toString());

   Attribute modCert = new BasicAttribute("userCertificate", cert.getEncoded());

   mods[0] = new ModificationItem(context.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, modCert);
   context.modifyAttributes(dn + "," + searchBase, mods);
```

Hope it helps someone...